# Ruby on Rails Form Calculator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I would like to build a calculator for my app. Before the users saves a record, it should be able to input some variables on a form and hit a "Calculate" button to see "how many units he needs to build something".

**I created a custom route:**

```
get 'product_stock_calculator/:product_id',       to: 'product_stocks#calculator'
```

**Model:**

```
class ProductStock < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class ProductStocksController < ApplicationController
...
   def calculator
     @product_stock = ProductStock.new
     @product_stock.product_id = params[:product_id]
   end
...
end
```

**View:**

```
product_stocks/calculator.html.erb


<%= simple_form_for(@product_stock) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :product_id, label: 'Producto', collection: Product.all, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :number_of_boxes, label: 'Units to build', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How can I submit the form, make some calculations and render a view to show the calculation results without saving the record?

Comment: It looks like you really want to use "form_tag" with a custom action rather than trying a resource-based route.  Probably need more information to answer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Same way as you would do anything.

You submit the form to a route pointing to a controller action, where you will perform your calculations based on the parameters.

For example:

routes.rb:

```
match '/calculate', to "productstocks#calculate", via: 'post', as: :calculate
```

In your controller:

```
def calculate
    @productstock = Productstock.new(productstock_params) # strong parameters here
    @result = params[:productstock][:param1] * params[:productstock][:param2] # for example
    render 'calculator' # this will render with the unsaved 
                        # new @producstock and you can use @result too in your view
end
```

And you set form's action to `calculate_path`